# How can I select the iframe of the wysihtml5 editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I'm using the wysiwyg editor wysihtml5 with the bootstrap-wysihtml5 extension.

I'm building a character counter and want to put a red border on the editor area when a maxlength is reached.

But how can I, in javscript, select the textarea? In the source, it's not a textarea, it's an iframe, and it doesn't have a unique ID or anything. I'm actually creating several editors on one and the same page so I need to distinguish which one I am selecting.

Answer (score 2):

How about following solution (using the data):

```
$($('.textarea').data("wysihtml5").editor
```

Or you can access the editor object via the `this` reference in events:

```
$('.textarea').wysihtml5({
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var editor = this;
      $(editor.currentView.doc.body).on("keydown",function(event) {
        var l = event.currentTarget.innerText.length;
        if(l >= 50) {
          $(editor.currentView.iframe).addClass('redborder');
          $(editor.textareaElement).addClass('redborder');
        } else {
          $(editor.currentView.iframe).removeClass('redborder');
          $(editor.textareaElement).removeClass('redborder');
        }
      }); 
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is that onChange the inline styles of the iframe get overriden, for which you have to use a class with important:

```
.redborder {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

This solution works at least with my fork: https://github.com/Waxolunist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower/

You have to test which object attribute contains an accurate length value, because innerText does not contain any markup.

Comment: Dude it was driving me crazy, thanks for this answer